# Boolean Query In Room Database

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

I am getting my objects from the web and directly inserting them into **ROOM DATABASE**

```
@Entity(tableName = Constants.TABLE_OBJECT_ICONS)
public class ObjectClass {

    @PrimaryKey()
    @SerializedName("id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = Constants.KEY_OBJECT_ID)
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("controlUnit")
    @ColumnInfo(name = Constants.KEY_CONTROL_UNIT)
    @Expose
    private String controlUnit;

    @SerializedName("isStack")
    @ColumnInfo(name = Constants.IS_STACK)
    @Expose
    private Boolean isStack;

    public Boolean getStack() {
        return isStack;
    }

    public void setStack(Boolean stack) {
        isStack = stack;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getControlUnit() {
        return controlUnit;
    }

    public void setControlUnit(String controlUnit) {
        this.controlUnit = controlUnit;
    }

}
```

Now the problem is, I am inserting *Boolen* datatype into DB and room is mapping it into 0 and 1, but when I'm trying to fetch data my **getStack()** methods returns null

**UPDATE**

Here is the **Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface ObjectDao {

    @Insert
    void insertObject(ObjectClass objectClass);

    @Query("DELETE FROM object_icons")
    void deleteAllObjects();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM object_icons WHERE object_id=:id AND site_id=:siteId")
    Single<ObjectClass> getObjectById(String id, String siteId);

    @Query("SELECT object_name FROM object_icons WHERE object_id=:id AND site_id=:siteId")
    String getObjectNameById(String id, String siteId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM object_icons WHERE object_keyword=:key AND site_id=:siteId")
    ObjectClass getObjectByKey(String key, String siteId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM object_icons WHERE site_id=:siteId")
    Single<List<ObjectClass>> getObjectIconsList(String siteId);

}
```

and after taking the Database I opened it into *SQLite Online* following is the structure of database.

[image]

Comment: Kindly upvote if not able to answer!

Comment: You need to give a bit more context to the question. 1. Post the fetch query from you Dao, 2. Is it actually inserting the boolean value, if so how did you verify it ?

Comment: @BadhrinathCanessane Question has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, could you also post the value for Constants.IS_STACK. Make sure the name of the columns is correct in your Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130777/does-room-database-support-boolean-variables-in-entity) Room should convert `1` to `true` when you're reading your object. Also it seems that if you're migrating from Sqlite to Room you might have some issue with `Boolean` and `Integer` type, I don't know if this is your situation but here is a link in case: [room migration using existing boolean column types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261997/room-migration-using-existing-boolean-column-types/55304942#55304942)

Comment: True answer, thank you.